# What is the best approach to working out if I have retweeted a tweet from another user, via the Twitter API?

Tags: twitter

So, I am currently working on an application that allows me to search journalists and view their contact details including, among other things, their latest tweets.

Calling the Twitter API is no problem at all, and I have a list of tweets for the current journo showing up fine.  However, I am trying to decide the best approach to seeing if I (the user logged into our application) have retweeted any of the journo's tweets, so that I can display the tweet as having been retweeted.

Looking at the API documentation, I am looking into the following options:

> 1 - Use [/statuses/retweeted_by_me](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/statuses/retweeted_by_me) to get the list of tweets that I
>   have retweeted, specifying **max_id** to be the highest id from the
>   list of tweets for the journo I am looking at.  What I am not sure of
>   here is if the max_id is going to limit by the max id of my tweets or
>   the max id of the retweeted tweets.
>
> 2 - Use [/statuses/:id/retweeted_by](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/statuses/%3aid/retweeted_by) for each of the journo's tweets to 
>   get a list of all the users who have retweeted that tweet and to check to 
>   see if my user is in the returned list of users.  Downfalls of this is that there
>   could be thousands of retweeters and I can only return a maximum of
>   100 at a time.  That could mean a lot of requests just to find if I
>   retweeted one tweet.  This also means that I need to do this for each
>   of the journo's tweets as opposed to getting the list of all my
>   rewteets above.
>
> 3 - Use [/statuses/retweets/:id](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/statuses/retweets/%3aid) to get a list of the retweets for
>   each of the journo's tweets.  This option has the same limitations as
>    #2.

I'm currently leaning towards #1, however, I'm not sure as yet if this will work.  I need to do some more investigation.  In the mean time, my question to you is:

**What is the best approach to working out if I have retweeted a tweet from another user?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so I must have been having a brain fart moment when looking into this yesterday.  It occurred to me this morning that you can simply make an authenticated call to `/statuses/user_timeline` which will set the `retweeted` property to true if you have retweeted that tweet.

Simples.